# How to get logrus to print stack of pkg/errors

Tags: go

I'm using github.com/sirupsen/logrus and github.com/pkg/errors. When I hand an error wrapped or created from pkg/errors, all I see in the log out is the error message. I want to see the stack trace.

From this issue, https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/issues/506, I infer that logrus has some native method for working with pkg/errors.

How can I do this?

Comment: Was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54310175), then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54310884/) and then [there](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/ajby88/how_to_get_stack_traces_in_logrus/). Now here comes this new question about the same matters, with no references to prior discussions and with a self-provided answer basically copied from [there](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/ajby88/how_to_get_stack_traces_in_logrus/eeuuvr1). Well… I dunno but this feels… strange.

Comment: Spamming isn't the way to go mate. I've noticed you come from a Java background... please understand that go isn't Java, and errors aren't exceptions. (also: `logrus.Errorf("%+v", err)`)

Comment: I have tried to help you on a number of your previous, nearly identical posts, and you became hostile. I don't think it's an accurate portrayal to say you were "harassed."  But putting that all aside, my main sugestion to you was to read the documentation, because I know from personal experience that this is possible to do. By all indications, you've refused to do this. My answer below is further evidence that you haven't even read the `pkg/errors` documentation, which would make this task incredibly easy for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inference is wrong. Logrus does not actually know how to handle the error.
**Update** the Logrus team official said that this is NOT a supported feature, https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/issues/895#issuecomment-457656556.

**A Java-ish Response**
In order to universally work with error handlers in this way, I composed a new version of Entry, which is from Logrus. As the example shows, create a new Entry with what ever common fields you want (below the example is a logger set in a handler that keeps track of the caller id. Pass PgkError through your layers as you work the Entry. When you need to log specific errors, like call variables experiencing the error, start with the PkgError.WithError(...) then add your details.

This is a starting point. If you want to use this generally, implement all of the Entity interface on PkgErrorEntry.  Continue to delegate to the internal entry, but return a new PkgErrorEntry. Such a change would make the value true drop in replacement for Entry.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "strings"

    unwrappedErrors "errors"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

// PkgErrorEntry enables stack frame extraction directly into the log fields.
type PkgErrorEntry struct {
    *logrus.Entry

    // Depth defines how much of the stacktrace you want.
    Depth int
}

// This is dirty pkg/errors.
type stackTracer interface {
    StackTrace() errors.StackTrace
}

func (e *PkgErrorEntry) WithError(err error) *logrus.Entry {
    out := e.Entry

    common := func(pError stackTracer) {
        st := pError.StackTrace()
        depth := 3
        if e.Depth != 0 {
            depth = e.Depth
        }
        valued := fmt.Sprintf("%+v", st[0:depth])
        valued = strings.Replace(valued, "\t", "", -1)
        stack := strings.Split(valued, "\n")
        out = out.WithField("stack", stack[2:])
    }

    if err2, ok := err.(stackTracer); ok {
        common(err2)
    }

    if err2, ok := errors.Cause(err).(stackTracer); ok {
        common(err2)
    }

    return out.WithError(err)
}

func someWhereElse() error {
    return unwrappedErrors.New("Ouch")
}

func level1() error {
    return level2()
}

func level2() error {
    return errors.WithStack(unwrappedErrors.New("All wrapped up"))
}

func main() {
    baseLog := logrus.New()
    baseLog.SetFormatter(&logrus.JSONFormatter{})
    errorHandling := PkgErrorEntry{Entry: baseLog.WithField("callerid", "1000")}

    errorHandling.Info("Hello")

    err := errors.New("Hi")
    errorHandling.WithError(err).Error("That should have a stack.")

    err = someWhereElse()
    errorHandling.WithError(err).Info("Less painful error")

    err = level1()
    errorHandling.WithError(err).Warn("Should have multiple layers of stack")
}
```

**A Gopher-ish way**
See https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/ajby88/how_to_get_stack_traces_in_logrus/ for more detail.

Ben Johnson [wrote](https://middlemost.com/failure-is-your-domain/) about making errors part of your domain. An abbreviated version is that you should put tracer attributes onto a custom error. When code directly under your control errors or when an error from a 3rd party library occurs, the code immediately dealing with the error should put a unique value into the custom error. This value will print as part of the custom error's `Error() string` implementation.

When developers get the log file, they will be able to grep the code base for that unique value. Ben says "Finally, we need to be able to provide all this information plus a logical stack trace to our operator so they can debug issues. Go already provides a simple method, error.Error(), to print error information so we can utilize that."

Here's Ben's example

```
// attachRole inserts a role record for a user in the database
func (s *UserService) attachRole(ctx context.Context, id int, role string) error {
    const op = "attachRole"
    if _, err := s.db.Exec(`INSERT roles...`); err != nil {
        return &myapp.Error{Op: op, Err: err}
    }
    return nil
}
```

An issue I have with the grep-able code is that it's easy for the value to diverge from the original context. For example, say the name of the function was changed from attachRole to something else and the function was longer. It possible that the op value can diverge from the function name. Regardless, this appears to satisfy the general need of tracing to a problem, while treating errors a first class citizens.

Go2 might throw a curve at this into more the Java-ish response. Stay tuned.
https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/changes/97/159497/3/design/XXXXX-error-values.md

Answer (score 9):

The comment on your Logrus issue is incorrect (and incidentally, appears to come from someone with no affiliation with Logrus, and who has made no contributions to Logrus, so not actually from "the Logrus team").

It is easy to extract the stack trace in a `pkg/errors` error, [as documented](https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/errors#hdr-Retrieving_the_stack_trace_of_an_error_or_wrapper):

```
type stackTracer interface {
        StackTrace() errors.StackTrace
}
```

This means that the easiest way to log the stack trace with logrus would be simply:

```
if stackErr, ok := err.(stackTracer); ok {
    log.WithField("stacktrace", fmt.Sprintf("%+v", stackErr.StackTrace()))
}
```

As of today, when [my a pull request of mine was merged with `pkg/errors`](https://github.com/pkg/errors/pull/197), this is now even easier, if you're using JSON logging:

```
if stackErr, ok := err.(stackTracer); ok {
    log.WithField("stacktrace", stackErr.StackTrace())
}
```

This will produce a log format similar to "%+v", but without newlines or tabs, with one log entry per string, for easy marshaling into a JSON array.

Of course, both of these options force you to use the format defined by `pkg/errors`, which isn't always ideal. So instead, you can iterate through the stack trace, and produce your own formatting, possibly producing a format easily marshalable to JSON.

```
if err, ok := err.(stackTracer); ok {
        for _, f := range err.StackTrace() {
                fmt.Printf("%+s:%d\n", f, f) // Or your own formatting
        }
}
```

Rather than printing each frame, you can coerce it into any format you like.

Comment: As I've said before, the purpose of the question was to seamlessly get stacktrace as one would in every other language. You answer does not support the resolution of the that goal. The request wants to add the error WithError to then have the stack automatically added to the the log output. Your solution requires casting and formatting every place one may seek to add an error to a log. This is not convenient. You could have also offered the Go-ish response below stating that errors should be logical components of domains which track their logical stack.

Comment: Are you claiming, and if so please show your work, that there is some way, built in and activateable in Logrus, to so entry.WithError(aWrappedError) and get the logger to create a full stack? That is the question.

Comment: There's no "seamless" way to do this, but you never asked for that, either. But there is a way to get at the stack trace, and add it with `WithFields`. If you want it with `WithError`, then you either need to patch logrus (which should be trivial--whether they would accept a PR or not, I don't know), or provide your own wrapper, which provides this functionality (this is the approach I have always taken).

Comment: If you simply want _every_ error to include a stack trace in the `error` field, you can also accomplish this with a custom `error` type.  There's no straight-forward answer, because there's no obvious way to do this. And your question is not specific enough to dictate all possible methods. This is why "read the docs" is honestly the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom hook to extract stacktrace

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

type StacktraceHook struct {
}

func (h *StacktraceHook) Levels() []logrus.Level {
    return logrus.AllLevels
}

func (h *StacktraceHook) Fire(e *logrus.Entry) error {
    if v, found := e.Data[logrus.ErrorKey]; found {
        if err, iserr := v.(error); iserr {
            type stackTracer interface {
                StackTrace() errors.StackTrace
            }
            if st, isst := err.(stackTracer); isst {
                stack := fmt.Sprintf("%+v", st.StackTrace())
                e.Data["stacktrace"] = stack
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    logrus.SetFormatter(&logrus.TextFormatter{DisableQuote: true})
    logrus.AddHook(&StacktraceHook{})

    logrus.WithError(errors.New("Foo")).Error("Wrong")
}
```

Output

```
time=2009-11-10T23:00:00Z level=error msg=Wrong error=Foo stacktrace=
main.main
    /tmp/sandbox1710078453/prog.go:36
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594
```